# Download html of a webpage thats already loaded

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am writing a program using Python and selenium to automate logging into a website. The website asks a security question for additional verification. Clearly the answer I would send using "send_keys" would depend on the question asked so I need to figure out what is being asked based on the text. BeautifulSoup can be used to parse through the HTML but in all the examples I have seen you have to give a URL to then read the page content. How do I read the content of a page that's already open? The code I am using is:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
chromedriver = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\chromedriver.exe'  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)  
browser.get('http://www.aaaa.com')  
loginElem = browser.find_element_by_id('bbbb')  
loginElem.send_keys('cccc')  
passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_id('dddd')  
passwordElem.send_keys('eeee')  
passwordElem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

The page with the security questions loads after this and that's the page I want the URL of.
I also tried finding by element but for some reason it wasnt working which is why I am trying a workaround. Below is the HTML for the entire div class where the question is. Alternatively maybe you can help me search for the right one.

```
<div class="answer-section"> 
<p> Please answer your challenge question so we can&nbsp;help
verify&nbsp;your identity.
</p> <label for="tlpvt-challenge-answer"> What is the name of your dog?
</label>
<input type="text" id="tlpvt-challenge-answer" class="tl-private gis- mask"
name="challengeQuestionAnswer" value=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need `BeautifulSoup` for that? you can just get the HTML element with `loginElem = browser.find_element_by_id('bbbb')` or whatever other method in `selenium` and then doing `loginElem.text` (that was an example, i'm not saying that this is the element which text you need to parse)

Comment: I added some more info to the question which should explain why I am trying the above route

Answer (score 0):

well if you want to use `BeautifulSoup` you can retrieve the source code from the webdriver and then parse it:

```
chromedriver = 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\chromedriver.exe'  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http://www.aaaa.com')

# call page_source attr from a webdriver instance to
# retrieve HTML source code
html = browser.page_source

# parse it with BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
label = soup.find('label', {'for': 'tlpvt-challenge-answer'})
print label.get_text()
```

output:

```
$ What is the name of your dog?
```